# I am getting this error in android and dont know the reason

Tags: android, sidebar

Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter$1.class

I am getting this error on android , i dont understand why, if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating the android.support.V4 library
Right click on project go to properties click on android 
check library if v7 is already their.
delete the v4 library from your projects libs folder.

Comment: Thank you... problem solved already.. and you are right , i duplicated the libraries